# Is there an efficient way to 'enumerate' a namespace in C++?

Tags: c++, namespaces

Is there a way to programmatically enumerate a namespace and its members in C++?

I have a large C++ program which utilizes several namespaces. I am unfamiliar with the codebase, and would like to determine which functions/classes/variables are associated with which namespaces.

My current approach involves simply removing the 'using namespace' directives one by one and checking what breaks during compilation, but I assume there is a much better way to achieve the same goal.

Comment: What compiler / IDE do you use?

Comment: emacs and g++ (4.4) - removing the directives and compiling gets the job done, I was just wondering if there might not be a more elegant/efficient/effective way to go.

Comment: removing the `using namespace` is a goal in itself :) Also consider (adding to the list of external tools): ctags y cosas por el estilo.

Comment: @dribeas indeed, my ultimate goal in this case is to get rid of these namespace dependencies~ and thanks for the ctags suggestion. the rest of that means what, 'and things for the style'?  sorry my spanglish is a bit rusty!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible in C++.

However, you can use external tools, such as [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org), that will create documentation (HTML, and other formats) that will list all the members of your namespaces.

Comment: That is awesome.  I had no idea doxygen could be run on arbitrary, undocumented source code.  This was hugely helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, introspection is NOT one of C++'s big features. There's no way (within the language) to do what you want. You'll need an external code analysis tool (something that can parse the code and build a reference) to do the job. I use [cscope](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/) for a lot of analysis, but to my knowledge it doesn't really know about namespaces, so probably not the right tool for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a C++ front-end (e.g. [Elsa](http://www.scottmcpeak.com/elkhound/sources/elsa/index.html)) to do the job for you.

Also consider using a good IDE that has a 'Go To Defiinition' functionality (e.g. Microsoft Visual Studio).

Answer (score 1):

You can start by running [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/index.html) to generate an index of all the functions/classes/namespaces defined in your project.  Make sure to edit the settings to generate the index for undocumented symbols.

Answer (score 0):

If you know which namespaces you're looking for, you can just generate a map file (`g++ -Wl,-Map,MyMapFile.map`). Then search for e.g. `MyNamespace::` in the map file.